# Apache doesn't let me in, but it should

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress

**EDIT**

The accepted answer below is the correct one assuming (as I thought) that the server is v2.2.

Instead, I discovered the server is apache 2.4 instead, so the real solution was to use the new directives.
Please see my comment below the accepted answer.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

in mydomain.com/wp-admin I placed a .htaccess with something like

```
# note: the ip here is a fake
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.1.101
```

But I now get a 403 error. The domain and IP here are fake, but the real IP I'm using is correct since I can see it form logs, that are something like:

> www.example.com 192.168.1.101 - - [10/Jan/2017:10:51:52 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 403 518 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"

So it's really strange, I should be able to enter. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Order](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order) directive documentation.

You need something like:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from 192.168.1.101
```

Comment: Just to quickly explain it for him: the order in which you write the commands (allow/deny) in the "order" row decides what your server interprets first. In your case you first write "deny" and then later "deny from all". Since the deny command has higher priority your server denies all and doesnt even check for 192.168.1.101 anymore, since you already denied all connections for **all**.
If you write `order allow,deny` your server first allows 192.168.1.101 and then denies everyone else.

Comment: Ok, I discovered that the real problem was in fact the apache version! ;) On that server it's 2.4, and those directives are not supported anymore. The solution was to use new directives like `Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` or `Require all denied`. See [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)